# Google Pagespeed Plugin causing errors

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amazon-web-services, server, google-pagespeed

I am having a really strange issue.  We use Digital Ocean for dev servers and Amazon AWS for production servers.  We push our dev sites to the production sites once the client has approved the website.  Today, we went ahead and pushed a website and we are experiencing some errors that we just can't simply figure out how to fix it.

The error is as follows:

```
ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1)
at Function.each (jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js:1)
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js:1)
at h (ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1)
at i (jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js:1)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js:1)
at a.fn.init.n.fn.ready (jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js:1)
at ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1
at ultimate.min.js,qver=3.16.7.pagespeed.jm.CdtAB3JioC.js:1
```

We use the Google Pagespeed server plugin on our AWS servers which I believe is interfering with ultimate.min.js which is deriving from "Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer".  Unfortunately we can't disable the Ultimate because the website is built using a ton of they shortcodes.

Can anyone help us figure out a possible way to fix this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sure!  I am sorry I did not know that.  I will refrain in the future.